Linker error appear when I try to call any libusb function from libusb.h in Qt project: "undefined reference to `udev_device_get_action'"
Linker error appear when I try to call any libusb function(int status = libusb_init(NULL);) from libusb.h in Qt 5.12.5 C++ project.
I built a cross-compiler for Raspberry Pi3 under Ubuntu, the cross-compiler works fine. When I added the libusb library to the project (added the LIBS += -lusb-1.0 library in the pro file) and included the libusb.h header file, as far as I understood, I got errors from the linker, they are below. I have no idea what the problem is and what I did wrong? If I choose a kit with a compiler for Linux (desktop), then everything compiles fine. On Raspberry itself, if I write code in C and compile the program using GCC, which is installed on Raspberry, then there are no problems either. Here is a qmake call to the cross-compiler (with C++ compiler for Raspberry):
> /home/vboxuser/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake /home/vboxuser/myproj/11-USBproject/usbCashboxExchange/usbCashboxExchange.pro -spec /home/vboxuser/raspi/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++/ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug && /usr/bin/make qmake_all

I have the following errors:

03:26:16: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -j6

/home/vboxuser/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/qt5pi/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -o usbCashboxExchange main.o mainwindow.o qml_settings.o usbClass.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_qml_settings.o moc_usbClass.o   -L/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/lib -lusb-1.0 /home/vboxuser/raspi/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Widgets.so /home/vboxuser/raspi/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Gui.so /home/vboxuser/raspi/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so /home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so -lpthread
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`udev_hotplug_event':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to \`udev_device_get_action'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`udev_hotplug_event':
(.text+0x48): undefined reference to \`udev_device_get_devnode'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`udev_hotplug_event':
(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to \`udev_device_get_sysname'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`udev_hotplug_event':
(.text+0x90): undefined reference to \`udev_device_unref'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_event_thread_main':
(.text+0x1d4): undefined reference to \`udev_monitor_receive_device'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_start_event_monitor':
(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to \`udev_new'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_start_event_monitor':
(.text+0x2b0): undefined reference to \`udev_monitor_new_from_netlink'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_start_event_monitor':
(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to \`udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_start_event_monitor':
(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to \`udev_monitor_enable_receiving'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_start_event_monitor':
(.text+0x2e8): undefined reference to \`udev_monitor_get_fd'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_start_event_monitor':
(.text+0x3b4): undefined reference to \`udev_monitor_unref'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_start_event_monitor':
(.text+0x3cc): undefined reference to \`udev_unref'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_stop_event_monitor':
(.text+0x57c): undefined reference to \`udev_monitor_unref'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_stop_event_monitor':
(.text+0x594): undefined reference to \`udev_unref'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x678): undefined reference to \`udev_enumerate_new'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x688): undefined reference to \`udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x698): undefined reference to \`udev_enumerate_add_match_property'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x6a0): undefined reference to \`udev_enumerate_scan_devices'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x6a8): undefined reference to \`udev_enumerate_get_list_entry'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x6bc): undefined reference to \`udev_list_entry_get_name'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x6d0): undefined reference to \`udev_device_new_from_syspath'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x6d8): undefined reference to \`udev_device_get_devnode'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x6e8): undefined reference to \`udev_device_get_sysname'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x730): undefined reference to \`udev_device_unref'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x738): undefined reference to \`udev_list_entry_get_next'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_scan_devices':
(.text+0x748): undefined reference to \`udev_enumerate_unref'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-linux_udev.o): In function \`linux_udev_hotplug_poll':
(.text+0x7e8): undefined reference to \`udev_monitor_receive_device'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.a(pthread_create.o): In function \`\__pthread_create_2_1':
/build/glibc-lsttuD/glibc-2.28/nptl/pthread_create.c:697: undefined reference to \`\_dl_stack_flags'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o): In function \`\__pthread_initialize_minimal_internal':
/build/glibc-lsttuD/glibc-2.28/nptl/nptl-init.c:434: undefined reference to \`\_dl_pagesize'
/build/glibc-lsttuD/glibc-2.28/nptl/nptl-init.c:434: undefined reference to \`\_dl_init_static_tls'
/build/glibc-lsttuD/glibc-2.28/nptl/nptl-init.c:434: undefined reference to \`\_dl_wait_lookup_done'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o): In function \`\__pthread_get_minstack':
/build/glibc-lsttuD/glibc-2.28/nptl/nptl-init.c:443: undefined reference to \`\_dl_pagesize'
/home/vboxuser/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.a(unwind.o): In function \`unwind_stop':
/build/glibc-lsttuD/glibc-2.28/nptl/unwind.c:72: undefined reference to \`\__pointer_chk_guard_local'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: \*\*\* \[Makefile:162: usbCashboxExchange\] Error 1
03:26:17: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project usbCashboxExchange (kit: Qt 5.12.5 (qt5))
When executing step "Make"
03:26:17: Elapsed time: 00:00.


Please don't post the formatted text as a quotation and splitting it with blank lines and escaping characters, instead post the text as a code.

libusb requires linking with libudev and perhaps libdl.

adding other libraries(libudev,..) to the pro file solve these errors
